# Issue in modal bootstrap

Tags: php, sql, modal-dialog

[image: contact form]

I made simple contact form as above and get the content from the SQL:

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM docs ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

?>
```

and by "while" func everything is OK.

So I made a profile button "bootstrap Modal" to show the profile in the same page after clicking on it but the forms are doing good but all modals show the same ID, do not change with every contact form to show the data of this form, and also I want to active the rank button with SQL but don't have any idea how.

here is the full code:

```
        <?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM docs ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        ?>

               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details ">
                    <div class="well profile_view">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4 class="brief"><i><?php echo $row['name']; ?></i></h4>
                        <div class="right col-xs-7">
                          <h2><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h2>
                          <p><strong>personal information: </strong> <?php echo $row['about']; ?> </p>
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> address: <?php echo $row['address']; ?></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> phone: <?php echo $row['phone']; ?></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
                          <img src="images/x.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">profile</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Please post your html code as well

Comment: i post it, u can check it now and please check if it secure